# ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_2(...).grElementList is not a function

Tags: angular7

when I am resizing a window. below event is not detecting window resize instead of this error I get each time

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Error :

```
GuidanceReportComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_2(...).grElementList is not a function
        at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (GuidanceReportComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
        at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
        at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
        at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
        at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
        at core.js:21003
        at platform-browser.js:993
        at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
        at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the **Host Listener** Decorator, you are specifying Angular to listen to the window resize event which you are passing as an argument ($event).
When you write the event Handler onResize(event) you actually pass the event recorded by angular. Hence the code is throwing you an error. The Below Code should work well.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event)
  {
    this.innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
  }
```